# SDWebimage scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, sdwebimage

I use SDWebimage to load and cache pictures, and now I am looking for a way to swipe/scroll through the images. I've tried different approaches but I can't seem to get it working, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Tried MWPhotoBrowser ???/

Comment: This doesn't make use of SDWebimage caching, which is the most important thing in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do your scrolling image browser as you otherwise would, but instead of setting the `image` property synchronously, you just call the `SDWebImage` method `setImageWithURL` (from its `UIImageView` category).

To show you a quick and dirty implementation, create a `UIScrollView`, turn on paging, and in `viewDidLoad` you can set the content size and load the first image, like so:

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * [self.objects count],
                                           self.view.bounds.size.height)];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ImageBrowserObject *object = self.objects[0];
    [object scrollView:self.scrollView addImageViewIfNeededForIndex:0];
});
```

You also want to set up your controller as a delegate for that scroll view and then handle the `scrollViewDidScroll` event:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    static NSInteger lastKnownIndex = -1;

    NSInteger currentIndex  = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width + 0.5f;
    NSInteger nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    NSInteger prevIndex = currentIndex - 1;
    if (prevIndex < 0) prevIndex = 0;

    if (currentIndex == lastKnownIndex)
        return;

    // add the imageviews we need, remove the ones we don't

    [self.objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(ImageBrowserObject *object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (idx >= prevIndex && idx <= nextIndex)
            [object scrollView:scrollView addImageViewIfNeededForIndex:idx];
        else
            [object scrollView:scrollView removeImageViewIfNeededForIndex:idx];
    }];

    lastKnownIndex = currentIndex;
}
```

And my `ImageBrowserObject` is defined as follows:

```
@interface ImageBrowserObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ImageBrowserObject

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title URL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _title = title;
        _url = url;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)scrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView addImageViewIfNeededForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (self.imageView)
        return;

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(index * scrollView.frame.size.width,
                              0.0,
                              scrollView.frame.size.width,
                              scrollView.frame.size.height);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:self.url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    self.imageView = imageView;
}

- (void)scrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView removeImageViewIfNeededForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (!self.imageView)
        return;

    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    self.imageView = nil;
}

@end
```

This is a pretty simplistic implementation, but I suspect you get the idea.